# LetsEncrypt/Certbot Domain Verification with Redirect

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

Is it possible to 301 redirect from abc.com to a different domain xyz.com during cert creation/validation with certbot and complete the domain verification via xyz domain?
This question was asked in [letsencrypt forum](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/http-domain-verification-with-redirect/130449) already, and the answer was yes:

> that's possible - and that's a good solution with centralized systems

In my case the domains are on **different servers** having different IPs!!
And I really do not see how this should work. Reading the [letsencrypt manual](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/) it says:

> Let’s Encrypt gives a token to your ACME client, and your ACME client puts a file on your web server at http://<YOUR_DOMAIN>/.well-known/acme-challenge/.

So the acme client on abc.com puts the token into abc.com/.well-known/... Then the checking letsencypt bot is redirected to xyz.com. But the acme client on xyz.com has no idea about this process and cannot put the correct token into xyz.com/.well-known/...

Is such a scenario possible? If yes, please tell me how. If no, how can the redirect feature be used anyway?

Answer (score 1):

(this should probably be a comment, but its a bit long for the wee box).

I don't know if it is possible. If it is possible today AND NOT DOCUMENTED then it might not be possible tomorrow. IMHO if this works, then it's potentially a defect.

When I previously had to solve the issue of provisioning with certbot across a cluster, I chose a different path.

Since you need to designate a specific node to run the initial provisioning and refreshes from (unless you happen to have some cluster cron in place) I chose to proxy that location on the designated machine on the other nodes.

An additional complication was that I was replicating the config from this master node. I was using nginx, but the approach can be applied with Apache httpd and probably other webservers.

I had 2 files in /etc/nginx/snippets describing how to handle /.well-known/. One was a proxy config, one was an origin config. These were replicated across all nodes. There was also a symbolic link at /etc/nginx/snippets/certbot.conf This link pointed to a file **outside** the replication tree. That file was also a symbolic link pointing back to one of the two initial files. On the master node, it pointed to the origin server, elsewhere to the proxy definition.

In my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf files I simply included /etc/nginx/snippets/certbot.conf

Comment: That's kinda what I expected to hear. Thank you for sharing your approach.